# Exchange - How to reply from respective email accounts

Tags: exchange, outlook, outlook-2007

Folks!  Our network has several organizations using an Exchange server.  Every user has several email accounts such as test@company1.com, test@company2.com, test@company3.com and is using Outlook 2007.  What do I configure such that when the user gets email for account test@company2 and replies back to it, the email will say test@company2?  And when the user gets email for account test@company3 and replies to it, the email@company3?  Thanks, in advance, for your help!

Sincerely, Charles

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct (out-of-the-box) way to do that. In Outlook 2010 you can have multiple Exchange accounts. In 2007 you cannot.